# What data is saved in RSA private key?

Tags: rsa

What data is saved in RSA private key in openssl? How to view it?

Wikpedia says [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29#Using_the_Chinese_remainder_algorithm) variables are saved.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Perhaps you could elaborate a bit.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Why do you want to know?  How will you use the answer?  Some information on those sorts of topics might increase the odds that we can offer an answer that will be useful to you.

Comment: How to view it will greatly depend on how the private key is encoded. That said, I have often had success reading the private key certificate into Java and then accessing the info from there.

Comment: Are you talking about openssl compatible key? Can you give the code?

Comment: To view the details of an RSA key or certificate, use the following command:
openssl rsa -in key.pem -text –noout

Comment: This is already mentioned in the accepted answer.

Comment: See also [What is the SSL private key file format?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21102/what-is-the-ssl-private-key-file-format)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can print the data with (change PEM to DER if required):

`openssl rsa -in Alice.key -text -inform PEM -noout`

The following data is stored:

- Modulus ($n = pq$)
- Public exponent ($e$)
- Private exponent ($d = e^{-1} \pmod{\phi{(n)}}$)
- First prime ($p$)
- Second prime ($q$)
- First exponent, used for Chinese remainder theorem ($d_P = d \pmod{p - 1}$)
- Second exponent, used for CRT ($d_Q = d \pmod{q - 1}$)
- Coefficient, used for CRT ($q_{\mathrm{inv}} = q^{-1} \pmod{p}$)

Comment: That works :) Somehow I haven't got a notification or haven't noticed it. Why is all this data saved? Is it not enough to save just p, q, e and probably d? What are first and second exponent used for? Is there any integrity check performed to verify that these variables are consistent?

Comment: The "extra" info is probably saved for performance reasons. We wouldn't want to recompute things over and over for potentially lots of uses of the key.