# What is the SSL private key file format?

Tags: rsa, public-key, tls, file-format

I was researching about how to encrypt with RSA. I understood everything but not the format of the private keys.

In the phpseclib (RSA in PHP), you can import your private key (private.key format) and in the key file there is text like this:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIBOQIBAAJBAIOLepgdqXrM07O4dV/nJ5gSA12jcjBeBXK5mZO7Gc778HuvhJi+
RvqhSi82EuN9sHPx1iQqaCuXuS1vpuqvYiUCAwEAAQJATRDbCuFd2EbFxGXNxhjL
loj/Fc3a6UE8GeFoeydDUIJjWifbCAQsptSPIT5vhcudZgWEMDSXrIn79nXvyPy5
BQIhAPU+XwrLGy0Hd4Roug+9IRMrlu0gtSvTJRWQ/b7m0fbfAiEAiVB7bUMynZf4
SwVJ8NAF4AikBmYxOJPUxnPjEp8D23sCIA3ZcNqWL7myQ0CZ/W/oGVcQzhwkDbck
3GJEZuAB/vd3AiASmnvOZs9BuKgkCdhlrtlM6/7E+y1p++VU6bh2+mI8ZwIgf4Qh
u+zYCJfIjtJJpH1lHZW+A60iThKtezaCk7FiAC4= 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

But when I decode this with Base64 and then convert it to decimal it is just **one** number...
I thought you need both $p$ and $q$! My question:

**If I roll a dice (with 0 and 1) 1024 times and find the nearest prime number it would be my $p$ and I would do this process again so I get $q$, but how do I convert those numbers to the private.key format? And what's the difference?**

Comment: Just a small note: You published your private key on the internet. Now it's insecure and you have to generate a new one.

Comment: See also [What data is saved in RSA private key?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/what-data-is-saved-in-rsa-private-key)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Copy / paste that key into http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/asn1parse.php and you'll see that there are several different integers in there. $p$ is there, $q$ is there as is the exponent and several other integers to speed things up by taking advantage of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

The key is encoded using DER and derives semantic meaning via ASN.1. The following URL elaborates:

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#appendix-C

Quoting [I understand the mathematics of RSA encryption: How are the files in ~/.ssh related to the theory?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21289989/569976):

> The ASN.1 syntax for that DER-encoded string is described in
> [RFC8017](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.1) (aka [PKCS1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1)):
>
> ```
>   Version ::= INTEGER { two-prime(0), multi(1) }
>       (CONSTRAINED BY
>       {-- version must be multi if otherPrimeInfos present --})
>
>   RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
>       version           Version,
>       modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
>       publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
>       privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
>       prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
>       prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
>       exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
>       exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
>       coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
>       otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
>   }
> ```
>
> DER encoding uses a tag-length-value notation. So here's a sample
> private key:
>
> ```
> -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> MIICXAIBAAKBgQCqGKukO1De7zhZj6+H0qtjTkVxwTCpvKe4eCZ0FPqri0cb2JZfXJ/DgYSF6vUp
> wmJG8wVQZKjeGcjDOL5UlsuusFncCzWBQ7RKNUSesmQRMSGkVb1/3j+skZ6UtW+5u09lHNsj6tQ5
> 1s1SPrCBkedbNf0Tp0GbMJDyR4e9T04ZZwIDAQABAoGAFijko56+qGyN8M0RVyaRAXz++xTqHBLh
> 3tx4VgMtrQ+WEgCjhoTwo23KMBAuJGSYnRmoBZM3lMfTKevIkAidPExvYCdm5dYq3XToLkkLv5L2
> pIIVOFMDG+KESnAFV7l2c+cnzRMW0+b6f8mR1CJzZuxVLL6Q02fvLi55/mbSYxECQQDeAw6fiIQX
> GukBI4eMZZt4nscy2o12KyYner3VpoeE+Np2q+Z3pvAMd/aNzQ/W9WaI+NRfcxUJrmfPwIGm63il
> AkEAxCL5HQb2bQr4ByorcMWm/hEP2MZzROV73yF41hPsRC9m66KrheO9HPTJuo3/9s5p+sqGxOlF
> L0NDt4SkosjgGwJAFklyR1uZ/wPJjj611cdBcztlPdqoxssQGnh85BzCj/u3WqBpE2vjvyyvyI5k
> X6zk7S0ljKtt2jny2+00VsBerQJBAJGC1Mg5Oydo5NwD6BiROrPxGo2bpTbu/fhrT8ebHkTz2epl
> U9VQQSQzY1oZMVX8i1m5WUTLPz2yLJIBQVdXqhMCQBGoiuSoSjafUhV7i1cEGpb88h5NBYZzWXGZ
> 37sJ5QsW+sJyoNde3xH8vdXhzU7eT82D6X/scw9RZz+/6rCJ4p0=
> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
> ```
>
> Here's the hex encoding:
>
> ```
> 3082025c02010002818100aa18aba43b50deef38598faf87d2ab634e4571c130a9bca7b878267414
> faab8b471bd8965f5c9fc3818485eaf529c26246f3055064a8de19c8c338be5496cbaeb059dc0b35
> 8143b44a35449eb264113121a455bd7fde3fac919e94b56fb9bb4f651cdb23ead439d6cd523eb081
> 91e75b35fd13a7419b3090f24787bd4f4e196702030100010281801628e4a39ebea86c8df0cd1157
> 2691017cfefb14ea1c12e1dedc7856032dad0f961200a38684f0a36dca30102e2464989d19a80593
> 3794c7d329ebc890089d3c4c6f602766e5d62add74e82e490bbf92f6a482153853031be2844a7005
> 57b97673e727cd1316d3e6fa7fc991d4227366ec552cbe90d367ef2e2e79fe66d26311024100de03
> 0e9f8884171ae90123878c659b789ec732da8d762b26277abdd5a68784f8da76abe677a6f00c77f6
> 8dcd0fd6f56688f8d45f731509ae67cfc081a6eb78a5024100c422f91d06f66d0af8072a2b70c5a6
> fe110fd8c67344e57bdf2178d613ec442f66eba2ab85e3bd1cf4c9ba8dfff6ce69faca86c4e9452f
> 4343b784a4a2c8e01b0240164972475b99ff03c98e3eb5d5c741733b653ddaa8c6cb101a787ce41c
> c28ffbb75aa069136be3bf2cafc88e645face4ed2d258cab6dda39f2dbed3456c05ead0241009182
> d4c8393b2768e4dc03e818913ab3f11a8d9ba536eefdf86b4fc79b1e44f3d9ea6553d55041243363
> 5a193155fc8b59b95944cb3f3db22c9201415757aa13024011a88ae4a84a369f52157b8b57041a96
> fcf21e4d058673597199dfbb09e50b16fac272a0d75edf11fcbdd5e1cd4ede4fcd83e97fec730f51
> 673fbfeab089e29d
> ```
>
> The 30 is because it's a SEQUENCE tag. The 82025c represents the
> length. The first byte means the length is of the "long form" (82 & 80) and that
> the next two bytes represent the length (82 & 7F). So the actual length of the
> SEQUENCE is 025c. So after that is the value.
>
> Then you get to the version. 02 is of type int, 01 is the tag length
> and 00 is the value. ie. it's a two-prime key as opposed to a
> multi-prime key.
>
> [More info on the Distinguished Encoding Rules](http://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf).
>
> Trying to understand ASN.1 is a lot more complicated and a lot of it,
> for the purpose of understanding the formatting of RSA private keys,
> is unnecessary. For X.509 it becomes more necessary but RSA keys
> aren't nearly as complicated, formatting-wise, as X.509 certs.
>
> Hope that helps!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60211/discussion-on-answer-by-neubert-what-is-the-ssl-private-key-file-format).

Comment: Another useful ASN.1 decoder to help understand the structure: https://lapo.it/asn1js

Comment: Pasting a private key into a non-HTTPS protected site with no idea about what it's doing in the background with your key seems like a very bad idea!

Comment: I presume the person sharing the original key did not share a sensitive one, but I do think there should be a disclaimer associated with that comment to keep real private keys safe at home. I hope that anyone looking at this QA thread has that much sensibility, but it never hurts with a "here be dragons".

Answer (score 28):

It is correct that the given private key does not encode a single integer, and that it includes two primes $p$ and $q$. More precisely, that Base64 data encodes a string of bytes, which is an RSAPrivateKey encoded per ASN.1 DER-TLV (and thus [BER-TLV](https://www.itu.int/ITU-T/studygroups/com17/languages/X.690-0207.pdf#page=11)) following [PKCS#1v2.2 Appendix A.1.2](https://www.emc.com/collateral/white-papers/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp.pdf#page=41) (likely restricted to version 0). It decodes to:

- `30` ASN.1 tag for *sequence*, a BER-TLV tag (Application class, Constructed encoding, Tag number 0)
- `82 01 39` Length as prefix plus two bytes, of 0x139 = 313 (number of bytes following)

  - `02` ASN.1 tag for *int*, also a BER-TLV tag (Universal class, Primitive encoding, Tag number 2)
  - `01` Length encoded on one byte, of 0x01 = 1

    - `00` Version 0, meaning RSA private key with 2 primes
  - `02` ASN.1 tag for *int*
  - `41` Length encoded on one  byte, of 0x41 = 65

    - `00 83 8B 7A 98 1D A9 7A CC D3 B3 B8 75 5F E7 27 98 12 03 5D A3 72 30 5E 05 72 B9 99 93 BB 19 CE FB F0 7B AF 84 98 BE 46 FA A1 4A 2F 36 12 E3 7D B0 73 F1 D6 24 2A 68 2B 97 B9 2D 6F A6 EA AF 62 25` public modulus $n$ (big-endian, leftmost bit is sign)
  - `02` ASN.1 tag for *int*
  - `03` Length encoded on one byte, of 0x03 = 3

    - `01 00 01` public exponent $e$ (big-endian, leftmost bit is sign)
  - `02` ASN.1 tag for *int*
  - `40` Length encoded on one byte, of 0x40 = 64

    - `4D 10 DB 0A E1 5D D8 46 C5 C4 65 CD C6 18 CB 96 88 FF 15 CD DA E9 41 3C 19 E1 68 7B 27 43 50 82 63 5A 27 DB 08 04 2C A6 D4 8F 21 3E 6F 85 CB 9D 66 05 84 30 34 97 AC 89 FB F6 75 EF C8 FC B9 05` private exponent $d$ (big-endian, leftmost bit is sign)
  - `02` ASN.1 tag for *int*
  - `21` Length encoded on one byte, of 0x21 = 33

    - `00 F5 3E 5F 0A CB 1B 2D 07 77 84 68 BA 0F BD 21 13 2B 96 ED 20 B5 2B D3 25 15 90 FD BE E6 D1 F6 DF` secret prime $p$ (big-endian, leftmost bit is sign)
  - `02` ASN.1 tag for *int*
  - `21` Length encoded on one byte, of 0x21 = 33

    - `00 89 50 7B 6D 43 32 9D 97 F8 4B 05 49 F0 D0 05 E0 08 A4 06 66 31 38 93 D4 C6 73 E3 12 9F 03 DB 7B` secret prime $q$ (big-endian, leftmost bit is sign)
  - `02` ASN.1 tag for *int*
  - `20` Length encoded on one byte, of 0x20 = 32

    - `0D D9 70 DA 96 2F B9 B2 43 40 99 FD 6F E8 19 57 10 CE 1C 24 0D B7 24 DC 62 44 66 E0 01 FE F7 77` $dp=d\bmod(p-1)$ (big-endian, leftmost bit is sign)
  - `02` ASN.1 tag for *int*
  - `20` Length encoded on one byte, of 0x20 = 32

    - `12 9A 7B CE 66 CF 41 B8 A8 24 09 D8 65 AE D9 4C EB FE C4 FB 2D 69 FB E5 54 E9 B8 76 FA 62 3C 67` $dq=d\bmod(q-1)$ (big-endian, leftmost bit is sign)
  - `02` ASN.1 tag for *int*
  - `20` Length encoded on one byte, of 0x20 = 32

    - `7F 84 21 BB EC D8 08 97 C8 8E D2 49 A4 7D 65 1D 95 BE 03 AD 22 4E 12 AD 7B 36 82 93 B1 62 00 2E` $q_\text{inv}=q^{-1}\bmod p$ (big-endian, leftmost bit is sign)

Therefore, this private keys has:

- $n$ = 6889562268374622799957651484276189567066573692163081374402850932375514118031048420110853972747558241305562483958233191802399592639320405757333978594894373
- $e$ = 65537
- $d$ = 4036265671212347870735218712159303880670782869380678233214786480134242711167668040594757438422211656546040377235338723652323162649874081271989898105895173
- $p$ = 110926848377808511478526072563819593239744031998335766139683653481372583065311
- $q$ = 62109059881601353504240950986730444628975000449359215027377545384004575026043
- $dp$ = 6264251733315063261699879374379301990940883202249731761950794231267222026103
- $dq$ = 8414580201851449070969916288679366126930879182597013446268294634551118019687
- $q_\text{inv}$ = 57677188406707620788831013172875873422122983590947547357547002213122938372142

As expected, these values verify:

- $n=p\cdot q$
- $e\cdot d\equiv 1\pmod{\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)}$
- $dp=e^{-1}\bmod(p-1)=d\bmod(p-1)$
- $dq=e^{-1}\bmod(q-1)=d\bmod(q-1)$
- $q_\text{inv}=q^{-1}\bmod p$

The public modulus $n$ is 512-bit, which is too small to be safe.

---

If one draws $p$ and $q$ using 1024 dice throws for each, rounding to the nearest *lower* prime, $p$ and $q$ are about (and at most) 1024-bit each, thus the public modulus $n$ about 2048-bit, which is safe. With overwhelming odds, $p$ and $q$ are distinct.

It is customary and recommended to ensure that $n$ has *exactly* $k$ bits with $k$ a multiple of some power of two at least 64, and towards that goal to choose $p$ and $q$ above $2^{(k-1)/2}$.

It is customary and unobjectionable to choose $e=2^{16}+1=65537$, and towards that goal to choose $p$ and $q$ such that $p\not\equiv1\pmod{65537}$ and $q\not\equiv1\pmod{65537}$.

Afterwards, one

- computes $n$, $d$, $dp$, $dq$, $q_\text{inv}$, $d$; for $d$, among other options, one can

  - compute $d=e^{-1}\bmod((p-1)\cdot(q-1))$ as in the private key above,
  - compute $d=e^{-1}\bmod(\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1))$ for a slightly smaller $d$,
  - build $d$ from $dp$ and $dq$;
- encodes the private key per ASN.1 DER-TLV following PKCS#1v2 Appendix A.1.2, as above;
- converts to Base64;
- adds `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----` delimiters;
- adds line breaks as appropriate (including at least before and after each delimiter, except that a newline is not necessary at start of file).

Easily missed rules when encoding to ASN.1 DER-TLV by induction from example:

- length encoding (in the context of RSA, all length are usually in range [1..0xFFFF], but some implementations have a lower size restriction)

  - any length from 0 up to 0x7F is encoded as one byte in `00`..`7F`;
  - any higher length up to 0xFF is encoded as prefix `81` and one byte;
  - any higher length up to 0xFFFF is encoded as prefix `82` and two bytes;
  - any higher length up to 0xFFFFFF is encoded as prefix `83` and three bytes;
  - any higher length up to 0xFFFFFFFF is encoded as prefix `84` and four bytes;
  - the rule goes on for higher lengths, but some standards (including ISO/IEC 7816-4:2013, appendix E.2) explicitly exclude these.
- the byte representation of a non-negative integer must be the shortest big-endian byte representation with leftmost sign bit; therefore:

  - it starts with a byte in range `00`..`7F`;
  - and if that first byte is `00`, then the next byte (if present) must be in range `80`..`FF`.

Comment: Wouldn't each roll of a fair, 6-sided die contribute $\log_2(6) \approx 2.6$ bits to each number, or about 2647 bits after 1024 rolls?

Answer (score 11):

To conclude the answers here's a note about the simplest way (on linux at least) to view the contents of such keys with openssl:

```
$ openssl rsa -in test.key -text
Private-Key: (512 bit)
modulus:
    00:83:8b:7a:98:1d:a9:7a:cc:d3:b3:b8:75:5f:e7:
    27:98:12:03:5d:a3:72:30:5e:05:72:b9:99:93:bb:
    19:ce:fb:f0:7b:af:84:98:be:46:fa:a1:4a:2f:36:
    12:e3:7d:b0:73:f1:d6:24:2a:68:2b:97:b9:2d:6f:
    a6:ea:af:62:25
publicExponent: 65537 (0x10001)
privateExponent:
    4d:10:db:0a:e1:5d:d8:46:c5:c4:65:cd:c6:18:cb:
    96:88:ff:15:cd:da:e9:41:3c:19:e1:68:7b:27:43:
    50:82:63:5a:27:db:08:04:2c:a6:d4:8f:21:3e:6f:
    85:cb:9d:66:05:84:30:34:97:ac:89:fb:f6:75:ef:
    c8:fc:b9:05
prime1:
    00:f5:3e:5f:0a:cb:1b:2d:07:77:84:68:ba:0f:bd:
    21:13:2b:96:ed:20:b5:2b:d3:25:15:90:fd:be:e6:
    d1:f6:df
prime2:
    00:89:50:7b:6d:43:32:9d:97:f8:4b:05:49:f0:d0:
    05:e0:08:a4:06:66:31:38:93:d4:c6:73:e3:12:9f:
    03:db:7b
exponent1:
    0d:d9:70:da:96:2f:b9:b2:43:40:99:fd:6f:e8:19:
    57:10:ce:1c:24:0d:b7:24:dc:62:44:66:e0:01:fe:
    f7:77
exponent2:
    12:9a:7b:ce:66:cf:41:b8:a8:24:09:d8:65:ae:d9:
    4c:eb:fe:c4:fb:2d:69:fb:e5:54:e9:b8:76:fa:62:
    3c:67
coefficient:
    7f:84:21:bb:ec:d8:08:97:c8:8e:d2:49:a4:7d:65:
    1d:95:be:03:ad:22:4e:12:ad:7b:36:82:93:b1:62:
    00:2e
```

If you have only a public RSA key - just add `-pubin` flag to openssl.

Comment: To answer your last question I can share a Python script: http://pastie.org/9808687 though I am not sure if it is the best method for stackexchange..

Answer (score 3):

What about the beautiful images on this page, 
[Certificate Binary Posters part 1](http://www.cem.me/20141221-cert-binaries.html) and [part 2](http://www.cem.me/20150104-cert-binaries-2.html)? I'd believe they would be useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the Base64 string doesn't contain just the private key but a specific data structure with additional information. In particular, your data contains a RSAPrivateKey object, which contains several values, including primes p and q. You can see a description of that object [here](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_Formats#RSA_PrivateKey).