# What are the integers in an RSA PEM file?

Tags: rsa

I have an RSA Private key file `my_private_key.pem` with the header `-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----`. I can parse that with the `openssl` utility: `openssl asn1parse < my_private_key.pem`

That shows me a bunch of integers: a 4096 bit integer, a 17 bit integer, another 4096 bit integer, and then five 2048 bit integers.

I understand the textbook RSA primitive where the private key is $(p,q,e)$ where $p,q$ are large secret primes and $e$ is the encryption exponent where $\gcd(e, (p-1)(q-1)) = 1$ and you encrypt plaintext $m$ by $c \equiv m^e \pmod{N}$ where $N=p \cdot q$. How does that textbook version of RSA relate to these integer numbers I see in a `.pem` file?

I'm sure this is a newbie question. Where do I start to read on this?

Comment: See [this answer of mine](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/31810).

Comment: $d$ is the private exponent (for decryption and signing) and $e$ the public one (for encryption and  verification). The file structure is defined in PKCS1 republished as https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.2  ; the rest of PKCS1 explains how the CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem) components are computed and used, but you might want to start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28cryptosystem%29 for an appreciation of _why_ this is done.

Comment: The RFC Appendix was exactly what I was looking for. The whole RFC itself is extremely readable and helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a labeled example output (don't worry I created a new key):[image]

Which you can verify for example in Sage. Although, surprisingly, it apparently doesn't allow decryption because the exponent is too large.

Comment: There is a power-mod function which allows for such large exponents.