# See the RSA's $n = p q, e \text{ and } d$ from ssh-keygen

Tags: rsa, keys, prime-numbers, ssh

For learning purposes, how to get the RSA's parameters  (I use standard notation):

$n = p q $, where $p$ and $q$ are prime and $e$, $d$, such that $ed = 1 \ (mod\ \varphi (n)) $ when doing

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
```

i.e. how to get those parameters from the output:

```
----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----
F2847XAPM...
...
----END PRIVATE KEY----
```

Note: this question is the reverse of [What data is saved in RSA private key?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/what-data-is-saved-in-rsa-private-key): how to recover these parameters from the keys produced by `ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048` (and *not* how to ask sshkeygen or openssl to output them from the start).

Comment: please check following answer https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6593/what-data-is-saved-in-rsa-private-key   using `openssl rsa -in Alice.key -text -inform PEM -noout`

Comment: @gusto2 Very interesting, I'll look at this. Any idea for the reverse operation? How to go from `----PRIVATE KEY---- ... ` to these parameters?

Comment: "go from 'PRIVATE KEY' to parameters" means you want to read the PEM-format PRIVATE KEY file and output the fields in it? That's EXACTLY what `openssl rsa -in file -text -noout` does; `-inform PEM` is the default and not actually needed. `-in` means read from the file, and `-text -noout` means output the individual fields instead of a PEM blob. Assuming you mean the`ssh-keygen` in OpenSSH, that actually writes PEM-format 'RSA PRIVATE KEY' which is a slightly different structure but contains the same key fields so `openssl rsa` can and does display the same for both.