# Using RSA public key as private key and vice-versa

Tags: rsa, public-key

I am writing an application that involves checking to see if data has been created by me. I do this by encrypting the data with the private key on my server, and then decrypting it using the public key on the client. If the result matches the hashed version of the message then I know it came from me. However, I'm using RSA and so that means I have to flip the keys since I know you can't encrypt with a private key.

Here is how I am generating my keys:

```
private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)

public_key = private_key.public_key()

pem = private_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)

with open('private_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pem)

pem = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

with open('public_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pem)
```

However, here `private_key` is my public key and `public_key` is my private key. Is there something I need to change? I've heard public keys are generally smaller but I don't understand enough of the settings to tell if they're symmetric or not.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT:** They are definitely not symmetric. As suspected, my public key is much shorter. How do I reverse this?

**EDIT2:** How about signing/verifying instead?

Server:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes, serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
import base64
import uuid
import hashlib


message_id = uuid.uuid1()
with open("private_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
message = bytes(hashlib.sha3_256((str(message_id) + str(valid)).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(), "utf-8")
encrypted_data = private_key.sign(
    message,
    padding.PSS(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA3_256()),
        salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
        ),
    hashes.SHA3_256()
)
encrypted_data = str(base64.b64encode(encrypted_data), "utf-8")
```

Client:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization, hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
import hashlib
import base64


encrypted = response["encrypted"]
message_id = response["message_id"]
valid = response["valid"]
with open("public_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
        key_file.read(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )
message = bytes(hashlib.sha3_256((str(message_id) + str(valid)).encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(), "utf-8")
encrypted = base64.b64decode(encrypted)
try:
    public_key.verify(
        encrypted,
        message,
        padding.PSS(
            mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA3_256()),
            salt_length=padding.PSS.MAX_LENGTH
        ),
        hashes.SHA3_256()
    )
    print("Yes")
except InvalidSignature:
    print("No")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it more weak to encrypt with the private key RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76419/is-it-more-weak-to-encrypt-with-the-private-key-rsa)

Comment: @kelalaka Not exactly. It has led me to the idea of signing/verifying instead. I will post an edit, let me know what you think.

Comment: @kelalaka Done.

Comment: @mentallurg Check my edit

Comment: @JackP: *How do I reverse this?* - you don't need to reverse. See the link of *kelalaka*. The answers there explain that.

Comment: @JackP: *How about signing/verifying instead?* - Sure you can use RSA keys for digital signature.

Comment: @mentallurg Is my approach outlined in my edit suitable?

Comment: To me it looks OK: Hashing, padding.

Answer (score 3):

> I am writing an application that involves checking to see if data has been created by me.

That's known as verifying data that was signed. It is good practice.

> I do this by encrypting the data with the private key on my server, and then decrypting it using the public key on the client.

That's where it gets wrong. The server must *sign* with the private key, and then the client must *verify* the signature with the public key. In RSA there are commonalities between *sign* and *decrypt* (both include the private-key operation $x\mapsto y=x^d\bmod N$), and between *verify* and *encrypt* (both include the public-key operation $y\mapsto x=y^e\bmod N$), but there also are important differences. For this reason, well-designed APIs, and knowledgeable advisers, won't let you encrypt with the private key. <sub><sup>Don't even try. <sub><sup>Ever. <sub><sup>Forget about it.</sup></sub></sup></sub></sup></sub>

Since the API includes PSS, which is a signature padding, it most likely includes primitives to sign with [RSASSA-PSS](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=27). We are not a code review site, thus I won't try to find where. But my reading of `hazmat` is that primitives in that area are not meant for direct use, I would look elsewhere.

Edit: I do not immediately see an issue with the code as it [now stands](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/76866/4), except for naming tag and variable `encrypted`, which I guess are for a signature. But then I do not know this API, and we are not a code review site.

Comment: Would you agree with my approach shown in my edit?

Comment: You've just shown signature generation & verification using PSS. Presuming that your system is otherwise secure, yes, that's what it is made for. Note that you need to *trust* the public key before you can verify that the data was signed by the right party.