# Under What Conditions Will the Public and Private Keys Produced by RSA Algorithm Be Reversible?

Tags: rsa

Given p = 7 and q = 13, one can obtain n = 91, d = 29, e = 5. However, for plaintext with values less than the modulus both the public and private keys (n, d) and (n, e) are reversible, i.e. encrypting a plaintext value with either key and then using the same key a second time returns the original value.

What is the reason for this and under what conditions will this occur?

This question notes that there are values of p and q which will generate a public key **such that a message encrypted with the public key can also be decrypted with the public key for message values of less than the modulus**. Likewise, the private key thereby generated can be used to decrypt a message which was encrypted with the same private key. This question does **not** ask whether a message can be encrypted with the public key and decrypted with the private key.

The answer from Daniel S provides the information I was seeking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it more weak to encrypt with the private key RSA?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76419/is-it-more-weak-to-encrypt-with-the-private-key-rsa). **Also**, [Using RSA public key as private key and vice-versa](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76866/18298) **and** [Is RSA encryption with a private key the same as signature generation?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15997/18298)

Comment: More germane is [can a public key be same as private key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/71836/can-a-public-key-be-same-as-private-key) though none of these cover your question of when the circumstances can occur. For the answer to this, see below.

Comment: [Does RSA work for any message M?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1006/18298)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using RSA public key as private key and vice-versa](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76866/using-rsa-public-key-as-private-key-and-vice-versa)

Comment: The question is not a duplicate of any of the above Q. It's not (at least, only) asking if we can swap public and private exponents/keys. It asks if the public key is such that re-encrypting deciphers.

Answer (score 1):

Although RSA keys are usually described as solutions to $de\equiv 1\pmod{\phi(N)}$, there is a more precise equation $de\equiv 1\pmod{\lambda(N)}$ where $\lambda$ is the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). Any solution to the usual equation is a solution to the more precise equation.

In your case the Carmichael function is $\mathrm{LCM}(p-1,q-1)=12$. The choice of $e=5$ leads to the solution $d\equiv 5\pmod{12}$ to the precise equation, and $d=29$ is an equivalent decryption exponent.

Generically, this will occur when the choice of $e$ is a square root of one modulo the Carmichael function (in this case $5^2\equiv 1\pmod{12}$, but 1, 7 and 11 are other examples). In general, a number $n$ has $2^{\omega(n)}$ square roots of 1 where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$.

Comment: So in short, for $N=p\,q$ with $p$ and $q$ distinct odd primes : when $e^2\bmod\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)=1$.

Comment: @fgrieu Indeed.